# Bound for complex roots of polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

I am trying to prove that if $p(z)=z^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\dots+a_0$ then all the zeros lie in a circle of radius $R= \max\{1,|a_0|+|a_1|+|a_2|+\dots+|a_{n-1}|\}$

I'm trying to use induction  and perhaps Liouville's theorem, but I'm stuck. Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $|z_0|$ is larger than $\max(1, |a_0|+\cdots +|a_{n-1}|)$.  Estimate the size of $a_{n-1}z_0^{n-1}+ \cdots + a_0$ and compare that to $|z_0^n|$.  You should be able to show that $z_0^n$ is greater in absolute value, so $p(z_0)$ can't be zero.

Comment: why would that imply that p(z_0) can't be zero?

Comment: $p(z_0)$ is the sum of two pieces, $z_0^n$ and $a_{n−1}z_0^{n−1}+⋯+a_0$.  If one of these is bigger (in absolute value) than the other, then they can't possibly add to 0.

Comment: OK, I think I get it, I can apply the inductive hypothesis to the second piece and that does the trick, right?

Comment: You don't need induction.

Comment: Right, since $|z_0|$ is larger than R then $|z_0^n|$ is larger than R^n. On the other hand I can also write the size of the second part in terms of R and then some rewriting will yield the inequalities.

Comment: That sounds right.

Comment: ok, thanks, I was really so fixed in using induction I couldn't see any other way.