# proof complex inequality involves triangle inequality

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

Consider the polynomial
$P(z) = a_0 + a_1z + a_2z ^{2} + · · · + a_nz^{n}$ where $a_j$ starts at $0$ and goes to $n$ with fixed complex numbers with $n \geq 1$ and a cannot be $0$. Show that if $P(z) = 0$ then

$$
|z| ≤ \text{max} 
(1, {|a_0| + · · · + |a_{n−1}|\over|a_n|}) 
$$

I'm new to complex analysis and I'm finding it hard to even interpret what the question is asking for.
The only thing I can think to do is assume that $P(z)=0$ and $n$ is greater than one so I can work with the $z$'s, rather than just the constant. The inequalities kind of suggest to me that using the triangle inequality could prove useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bound for complex roots of polynomial](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1766072/bound-for-complex-roots-of-polynomial)

Answer (score 1):

If $|z|\leq 1$ then the bound works. Otherwise $|z|>1$ and $P(z)=0$ implies that
$$|z|=\frac{\left|-(a_0/z^{n-1} + a_1/z^{n-2} + a_2/z ^{n-3} + \cdot 
+a_{n-1})\right|}{|a_n|}\\\leq \frac{|a_0|/|z|^{n-1} + |a_1|/|z|^{n-2} + |a_2|/|z| ^{n-2} + \cdot 
+|a_{n-1}|}{|a_n|}\\\leq \frac{|a_0| + |a_1| + |a_2| + \cdot 
+|a_{n-1}|}{|a_n|}$$
where we used the triangle inequality and $1/|z|^k<1$.
Therefore
$$|z| ≤ \text{max} 
(1, {|a_0| + \cdots + |a_{n−1}|\over|a_n|}).$$

Comment: In the first and second lines, should a_2/z^{n-3} follow a_1/z^{n-2}?

Comment: @Kierra Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this isn't really complex analysis, at least it doesn't require any tools of complex analysis.

I don't really understand what you don't understand about the question, but you may start as follows: If $P(z)=0$, then 
$$
|z|^n=|z^{n}|=|\frac{a_0+a_1z+\dots+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}}{a_n}|
$$